# Secure cookie for http and https website in Django 1.3

Tags: django, security, python-2.7, session-cookies, load-balancing

I have implemented loadbalancing for my django website. My loadbalancing server is https but my individual servers are http. I have set `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` to True in my individual servers settings.py file.

If I hit the server directly with loadbalancer, Cookie is secured and working fine (Because the loadbalancing server is https secured).

But if I hit individual servers the page is redirected to the login page and the user won't be able to login (Because individual servers are not secured).

As per the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER), I have included `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` in settings.py but it supports only django 1.4 version. I'm using Django 1.3 for my website.

I need  to secure cookie for my loadbalancing server and the realips (individual servers)
Any solution in Django 1.3 ?

Thanks in advance